# Passing credentials from Jenkins credential manager to property file which is present in Jenkins workspace with sed -i

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

```
environment { 
TEST_CRED = credentials('testcred')
}
 stage("Test creds") {
            steps {
                sh """#!/bin/bash
                   sed -i '/:TESTCRED:/ c\\:TESTCRED: ${TEST_CRED_USR}' 
${WORKSPACE}/test/data/properties.txt
               """}
}
```

While sending this way I am able to send credentials but the problem is I am getting warning

> The following steps that have been detected may have insecure interpolation of sensitive variables (click here for an explanation):

How to avoid the warning?
I tried with three single quotes after sh but when I do it my pipeline script is failing

Answer (score 0):

A short answer would be, get rid of the double quotes in sh command around credentials and the warning should go away. However,
there are two problems with your code. 1) You are actually abusing the credentials by using the environment variable directly. 2) You are using the credentials in a double-quoted string (String interpolated). I would recommend the below approach.

```
pipeline {
 stages {
  stage( "Test creds" ) {
   steps {
    script {
      withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'testcred', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
         sh script: 'sed -i \\\'/:TESTCRED:/ c\\:TESTCRED: ${username}\\\:${password}\\\'' + "${WORKSPACE}/test/data/properties.txt", label: "test credentials"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```